# setState() in React not updating state onClick Switch (antd)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, antd, setstate

When we click on the switch the state "valueState" does not update I don't know why ??

Also, I have a "statusValue" type problem because "switch antd" accepts boolean by cons initial value of props is of type number

Here is the code I am using :

//**********************************Code**********************************//

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Switch } from "antd";
class UpdateCard extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        valueState: this.props.state.status,
    }
}

handleToggle = (checked) => {
    console.log("state",this.state.valueState);
    console.log("checked",checked);
   if (checked === false){
    this.setState({
        valueState:1
      });
   }else {
    this.setState({
        valueState:0
      });
   }
    console.log("handleToggle valueState",this.state.valueState);
  };

  render() {
    const { state } = this.props;

    var statusValue = false;

    if (state.status === 0) { statusValue = true; }
  return (
  <Form id='update-state-form' 
            onFinish={this.onFinish}
            onFinishFailed={this.onFinishFailed}
            initialValues={{
                name: state ? state.name : '',
                status: state ? state.status : false,
                color: state ? state.color :'',
            }}
        >
            <FormItem {...formItemLayout} 
               name="name" 
               label={<IntlMessages id="app.stateName" />} 
               rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input the name !' }]} 
            >
                <Input />
            </FormItem>

            <FormItem {...formItemLayout} 
               name="color" 
               label={<IntlMessages id="app.color" />} 
               rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input the color !' }]}
            >
                <CirclePicker color={state.color} />
            </FormItem>

            <FormItem {...formItemLayout} 
               name="status" 
               label={<IntlMessages id="app.status" />} 
               rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input the status !' }]}
            >
                <Switch  defaultChecked={statusValue}  onClick={this.handleToggle}/>
            </FormItem>
        </Form>
    );
}
}
export default connect(
 null,
  {
     updateStateCardAction,
  }
 )(UpdateCard );
```

//****************************** Show console.log  ******************************//
[image]

Comment: what is statusValue in switch ?

Comment: There are 2 things, when you are calling this.handleToggle() you are not passing any value as paramete and setState() is asynchronous so keep that thing in mind. Also onClick is simply passed as prop to the Switch component, so be sure to follow the documentation of 'antd', I personally haven't used this library :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you are missing on two main things here as long as I understood your problem :

1. **statusValue** has not been declared in the state. And it should be a boolean value in the state. From documentation of Ant-Design **defaultChecked** prop is set false. First make sure you declare **statusValue** as state variable:

   ```
   this.state = {
    valueState: this.props.state.status,
    statusValue:false
   }

   ... // and keep state in sync with the UI
   ```
2. Then you have to make sure to pass **statusValue** state in the **onClick** handler.

   ```
    <Switch  
         defaultChecked={this.state.statusValue}  
         onClick={()=>this.handleToggle(this.state.statusValue)}
     />
   ```

Comment: Thanks "Imran" when I try your solution I have a type problem because antd switch accepts type boolean I try to add "componentDidMount" to modify state "statusValue" to false when valueState equals 1 but the solution is failed

Comment: Dear @Wiem : Could you please show me where are you still facing the issue.I can go through some documentation of antd and I promise to help you :) Only if you could explain me about what you are trying to achieve from your code especially from Switch component I would be pleased to help you :)

Comment: Thanks Dear @Imran I solved the problem thanks a lot :)

Comment: @wiemkhardani Most Welcome Dear. If my answer has helped you in any way or form, you may accept it by clicking theapprove tick, so that others also find it useful. This encourages me to help more and more people :) Thank you . Do please approve it if you find my answer useful dear. Fee AmaanilLah !!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the value also.

```
<Switch  defaultChecked={statusValue}  onClick={(statusValue) =>this.handleToggle(!statusValue)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'antd';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      onCheck: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { onCheck } = this.state;
    console.log(onCheck);
  }

  handleToggle = (checked) => {
    const { onCheck } = this.state;

    if (checked) {
      this.setState({ onCheck: 1 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ onCheck: 0 });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { onCheck } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Switch defaultChecked={onCheck} onChange={this.handleToggle} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
}
```

Comment: Thanks "Max", but I have a problem because props "default Checked" accepts type boolean not type number.
this solution does not work correctly because intialValue of switch is wrong.

Comment: it's work for me, what you can do is defaultChecked={onCheck === 1 ? true : false}

Comment: I used this solution :  componentWillMount() {
        this.props.state.status === 0 ?
        this.setState({ statusValue: true })
        : this.setState({ statusValue: false })
    }